# Changing content type of .js.php files using .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess

I want to change the Content-Type HTTP header of some file endings to `application/javascript` so I don't get an error or warning in the browser. I got `.mjs` and `.js.php.` files. The latter are PHP scripts which output JavaScript code. I want to use a `.htaccess` file to change the content type and not PHP code for example.

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
AddType application/javascript .mjs
AddType application/javascript .js.php
```

It works for `.mjs` but not for `.js.php` files. I still get

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

How to fix it?

Update:

I renamed my file `file.js.php` to `file.mjs.php` and removed the `AddType` handler for `.js.php` (as suggested). So only the `.mjs` handler remains. But I still get `text/html` as `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found in the post
[Apache Configuring options for sub file type](https://serverfault.com/questions/227453/apache-configuring-options-for-sub-file-type/227611) :

> It is not how you should do it. Here's why: according to the [mod_mime
> documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext), apache treats the all of the sections of the
> filename which begin with dot as an extension. In the example you
> provided, if you have a file, say, `default.dyn.html`, it is treated
> as a `.dyn` *and* as a `.html` file simultaneously. If simultaneous
> handling happens to be impossible, apache processes the extensions
> from right to left. So, you can't define an "extension" which contains
> a dot.
>
> What you should do instead, it to define the "server-parsed" handler
> for the `.dyn` extension only. In this way, if you have a `.dyn.html`
> file, it will be registered to the server-parsed *handler* and to the
> text/html *mimetype*. Since these can coexist nicely, the file will be
> parsed, and will be served as an html page.

Comment: It doesn't work (see my update above). Perhaps my web server is not Apache? It says "Server: Apache" but I don't know if I can trust that.

Comment: From the [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext), there is priority to the right in case of conflict, so for `.mjs.php` we have that `.php` wins on content-type. If you want `.mjs` to win, you should call it `.php.mjs`.

Comment: When I do this the PHP code inside the file will no longer get evaluated. Maybe what I want to do is not possible easily.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for : [PHP - generating JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152055/php-generating-javascript).

Comment: As already said in the question I know it's possible to set the content type in the PHP file. But I wanted to set it in .htaccess because it's more beautiful. But seems that is not possible. But that is not wild because I will simply stick to setting it in the PHP file. Thank you for your effort.